# Distance from ellipses to static set of polygons

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, computational-geometry, boost-geometry

I have a static set of simple polygons (they may be nonconvex but are not self-intersecting) and a large number of query ellipses. Assume that this is all being done in 2D. I need to find the distance between each ellipse and the closest polygon to that ellipse. Distance is defined as the short distance between any two points on the ellipse and polygon respectively. If the ellipse intersects a polygon, then we can say the distance is 0 or assign some negative value.

A brute force approach would simply compute the distance between each ellipse and each polygon and return the lowest distance in O(mn) time where m is the number of polygons and n is the average number of vertices per polygon. I would like to reduce the m term here because I think I can cull the amount of polygons being considered though some spacial analysis.

I've considered a few approaches including Voronoi diagrams and R-trees and kd-trees. However, most of these seems to involve points and I'm not sure how to extend these to polygons. I think the most promising approach involves computing bounding boxes for each polygon and the ellipse and using an R-tree to find some set of nearby polygons. However, I'm not quite about the best way to find this close set of polygons. Or perhaps there's a better way that I'm overlooking.

Comment: how are you representing your ellipses? TTBOMK there's no library feature for that.

Comment: Please confirm that the ellipses have arbitrary orientations and sizes.

Comment: Yes, the ellipses have arbitrary orientations and sizes. I represent them currently with a point and two distances (the semi major and semi minor axes) but I'm open to changing the representation if needed.

Comment: Correction: I mean two vectors, not two distances, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using bounding boxes or disks has the benefit of reducing the work to compute a distance ellipse/polygon to O(1). And it allows you to obtain a lower and an upper bound on the true distance.

Assume you use disks and also enclose the ellipse in a disk. You will need to perform a modified nearest neighbors search, that enumerates the disks such that the lower bound of their distance to the query disk is smaller than the best upper bound found so far.

This can be accelerated by means of a k-D tree (D=2) built on the disk centers. You can enhance every node in the k-D tree with the radius of the largest and smallest disks in the subtree it roots. During the search you will use this information to evaluate the bounds without knowing the exact radii of the disks, but the deeper you go in the tree, the better you know them.

Perform a search to obtain the tightest upper bound on the distance, then a second search to enumerate all the disks with a lower bound smaller than the tightest upper bound. This will reduce the number of disks to be considered.

You can also use bounding boxes, and store the min/max width/height of the boxes in the tree nodes.

Comment: Maybe not the clearest explanation, and easier said than done, but I am pretty sure that a modified k-D tree approach can work, provided the polygons are sufficiently sparse. Other devices that accelerate a 2D range search can probably do.

Comment: I think I understand the approach and I see how this will speed up the search. One case I'm thinking about is when I get adversarial polygon where the polygon is fairly close to the ellipse but the upper bound on distance is much further away. However, I think I can mitigate this by computing the true distance to the polygon to get a tighter distance bound. But yeah, I think I'll try to use the rtree implementation in boost with bounding boxes for now and see how well it works.